# XML response from URL not correct in Java, but correct in browser

Tags: java, url, servlets, xmlhttprequest

Firs of all I want to say that I was able to read XML response from URL with the help of Stackoverflow. Thank you for this and many other helps. I read and printed the response (code below) but the result is not correct.

In browser shows me (correct):

```
<ENELIT>
<GESI>
<RI>
<NR id="008201dfa306f4a2" tu="N" nr="0412395504" ut="" cp="" dp="" tm="" ca="" da="" rt="" cc="4"/>
</RI>
</GESI>
</ENELIT>
```

And in Java it prints this (incorrect):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="/psiche/styles/IEStyle.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <SCRIPT FOR=window EVENT=onload LANGUAGE="JAVAScript">
      if (top.areaApplication != undefined)
      {
        alert("Sessione utente scaduta. Effettuare il logon");
        top.areaApplication.location = "/gesi/online/root/login.htm";
      } 
    </SCRIPT>
    <h2>Sessione scaduta, Effettuare il logon.</h2> 
  </body>   
</html>
```

How can I get the correct result? Thank you!

My code for getting and printing the response:
Example 1:

```
URL url = new URL("http://gesi-ro-test.banat.enelro:8010/dynamic/gesi/ri/elab/phonerequest/wind.serid=008201dfa306f4a2&nr=06648624&is=2011/04/20%2013:03:03.296&rt=RE/");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
      System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

Example 2:

```
URL url = new URL("http://gesi-ro-test.banat.enelro:8010/dynamic/gesi/ri/elab/phonerequest/wind.ser?id=008201dfa306f4a2&nr=06648624&is=2011/04/20%2013:03:03.296&rt=RE");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(line).append("\n");
}
stream.close();
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without speaking the particular language, it seems that you are required to login to the service before you can access your information.

Comment: But why in browser it returns the response without having to login?

Comment: @mamba Because your browser is probably storing an authentication cookie

Comment: OK, when I write it in Java program it works like a charm, but in servlet it still returns wrong. Why this happens?

Comment: It seems that my URL is not ok. I'll mark this answer as OK. Thank you!